# PEAR Mail_Mime overwrite header "To"

Tags: php, pear, roundcube, mail-mime

currently I'm working on a plugin for Roundcube using some functions of Mail_Mime.

At one point I have to replace the recipient of the mail with another one, so I use

```
$message->get();
$message->headers(array('To'=>implode(',', $recipients)), true);
```

This code is doing well. But there still is the "Envelope-To"-Header, so the mail will never reach the correct recipient. I can't replace it like follows:

```
$message->headers(array('To'=>implode(',', $recipients), 'Envelope-To'=>implode(',', $recipients)), true);
```

Can anyone help? I'm stuck with this.